# Facing issue Provisioning new app for Endeca - When running Initialize_services.bat

Tags: endeca

[05.31.18 11:18:58] INFO: Provisioning site from prototype...
    [05.31.18 11:18:58] SEVERE: Service Unavailable (503): [00:23:51] Workbench is starting up (112 of 112 bundles activated, 131 of 176 components ready)...
    Occurred while executing line 3 of valid BeanShell script:
    [[

```
1|
2|
3|    IFCR.provisionSite();
4|    CAS.importDimensionValueIdMappings("Discover-dimension-value-id-manager",
5|              InitialSetup.getWorkingDir() + "/test_data/initial_dval_id_mappings.csv");
6|

]]

[05.31.18 11:18:58] SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on object 'InitialSetup'. Releasing locks.

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke0 - null
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript - Error executing valid BeanShell script.
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility$HttpStatusException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility execute - Service Unavailable (503): [00:23:51] Workbench is starting up (112 of 112 bundles activated, 131 of 176 components ready)...

Failure to initialize EAC application.
```

Comment: You've tried to initialise the site before the ToolsAndFramework Service was fully started. Suggest you restart all the services again. If you are on 11.x you may also need to set your credentials before initialising the site using the `manage_credentials` script.

Comment: Sometimes a corrupted install of ToolsAndFrameworks also might cause the issue, reinstalling it will resolve the issue.  Try opening the workbench first (i.e. using http://localhost:8006/ifcr) before trying initializing the app.